# Getting value of CustomSetting in batch class

Tags: customsetting, custom

I have created on custom setting whose API name is "testCustom__c" In that custom setting i have created one text area field whose API name is "FieldsToSearch__c". Now i have added one data set into that custom setting.

```
Name: "Fields"
FieldsToSearch: "Name,MobileNumber"
```

Now i want to get values which i have in `FieldsToSearch` in My apex class. How can i get this?

Answer (score 3):

How about for hierarchical:

```
testCustom__c settings = testCustom__c.getInstance(); // for org wide
if( settings.Id == null ) settings = testCustom__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getUserId());
String fieldsToSearch = settings.FieldsToSearch__c;
```

You might also want to check for nulls first

or use SOQL for list (or hierarchy):

```
Select FieldsToSearch__c From testCustom__c;
```

Comment: I got this through SOQL but not using getInstance method. Is there any issue of profile.

Comment: Can you confirm what type of custom setting it is?

Comment: edited to add getting setting or a particular user

Comment: Be careful with checking `settings == null`.  Need to check `settings.Id == null` because the [no arg getInstance()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm) returns a new object if nothing is defined.

Comment: What type means?

Comment: i.e. whether its a List or Hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following if your custom setting is of list type.

```
map<string, testCustom__c> mMyCustomValues = testCustom__c.getAll();
```

or

```
List<testCustom__c> myCustomValues = textCustom__c.getAll().Values();
```

Once you have your list/map then loop through and check for values.

I don't believe there is an issue with profile is accessing the values.